# How to fix collapse that won't work (using Bootstrap 4.0.0)?

Tags: bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

Here is my code

```
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <p>Menus</p>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#employeeform" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#employeeform" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Employee</a>
                        <ul class="collapse" id="employeeform">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Add New Employee</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Edit Employee's Data</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#customerform" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#customerform" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Customer</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="customerform">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Add New Customer</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Edit Customer's Data</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, whenever i click on the a element (Employee and Customer), it can't do the dropdown... Here is the scripts i use :

```
    <!-- bootdtrap css cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- popper.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- ajax -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- fontawesome -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
```

I don't know where i gone wrong, any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place bootstrap.min.js at the end.

```
<!-- bootdtrap css cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- popper.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- ajax -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- fontawesome -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much!!! I don't know how but it works. Can you tell me why the bootstrap.min.js should be at the bottom? Is there some kind of hierarchy when we place scripts?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">Toggle second element</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1 multiCollapseExample2">Toggle both elements</button>
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown show">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work either, the dropdown menu won't show as i click the a that has button role. And, I don't think dropdown is the one i want to use on my case. As you see i was using collapse. Does dropdown work the same as collapse?

Comment: I just share how use collapse in bootstrap 4. And dropdown and colapse not same things. Dropdown for menu and collapse for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the info! turns out the root of the problem is I misplaced the script for bootstrap.min.js just as Venci has pointed out.